# How to assign DOM element ID's to properties in a Javascript function constructor

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a simple function constructor and want to assign a DOM element ID to one of the properties. When this is done outside of a constructor you have to put the ID in quotation marks IE getElementById(**" whatever "**);

In my constructor I am not sure if I need to do this, how do add them,  nor if I am formatting this correctly.

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="bookText" value="Book">
</form>

<script>

function Item(itemName,itemDomID){
this.itemName = document.getElementById(this.itemDomID);   
};

var mybook = new Item(book,bookText);       // new object.


</script>
```

Comment: Wait, I am slightly confused.  Do you want to save the id? cause at the moment, you are assigning the element to itemName

Comment: Your function looks like a useless wrapper for document.getElementById. Rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a simple function constructor and want to assign a DOM element
>   ID to one of the properties. When this is done outside of a
>   constructor you have to put the ID in quotation marks IE
>   getElementById(" whatever ");

An element ID is a string, assigning a string to an object property does not require a function, just an assignment:

```
mybook.book = 'bookText';
```

When passing values using variables, just use the variable name. The expression will be evaluated to return the value. The constructor should be (note changes to original):

```
function Item(itemName, itemDomID){

    this[itemName] = document.getElementById(itemDomID);   

}
```

Note the use of square brackets to assign the value of `itemName` to the new property name, rather than the literal string "itemName".

So when calling the constructor, string values can be passed:

```
var mybook = new Item('book', 'bookText');
```

The values will be assigned to the variables in the function in order, so `itemName` is assigned the value "book" and `itemDomID` is assigned the value "bookText".

Inside the constructor, the new object will be given a property named "book" with a value of whatever is returned by `document.getElementById('bookText')`, which will either be a reference to an element, or `null` if no element with that ID is found.

Comment: How come:  document.write(mybook.itemName);  displays undefined

Comment: Because `myBook` doesn't have an *itemName* property, the property name is set to the **value** of `itemName`, which is *book*. So try `mybook.book`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your constructor parameter should be string?
[try this in jsfriddle](http://jsfiddle.net/378m3/2/)

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="bookText" value="Book">
</form>

​function Item(itemName,itemDomID){
    this.itemName = document.getElementById(itemDomID).value;   
};

var mybook = new Item("book","bookText");       // new object.
```

Comment: I didn't intend for the .value of the DOM element to be passed but thanks for this regardless. I learned something inadvertently. And yes, it should have been string.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(this.itemDomID);
```

This will return the javascript object. you can use like

```
var refObj=document.getElementById(this.itemDomID);
```

var objName=refObj.id;